# After refreshing page how to store $stateparams param value in Angular Js?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router

In button click event my state is going to change from one state to another.thats way I am passing Id value by using **ui-sref**.

this is my button declaration for id:-
      `<button ui-sref="list({id:'{{id}}'}"></buton>`

In state I am getting value like

```
.state(list, {
 url: '/list',
 params:{id: 'null'},
 template:''
})
```

The url should not contain id value,thats way i choose the above approach.The param value getting fine in first time loading but when i am going to refreash the page the param value became null again.

My button is in one controller(a.controller.js), and /list is another controller(b.controller.js).After changing state I want id in b.controller.js.

I tried but i was getting a proper solution for this situation except local storage.I donot want to store my value in local storage.So please any one can help me solve this problem.

Comment: Question is not cleared.. Need more code related to button

Comment: *Here params value are not to shown in url , thats why I choose this approach*: and that's why refreshing the page loses the param. Having parameters in the URL is a good thing. That's how the web works: URLs identify resources.

Comment: How to you "refresh" the page in case?

Comment: read your post once. Does it makes sense.? is it giving any clarity to readers. ??

Comment: it's clear that why am getting some response right

Comment: @Aravind Sir ,Please can you check my sentence and spelling. Is it fine to understance now for you.And if you get the question then please answer this.

Comment: Let me be precise. please update the full config and relevant controller codes with a.controller b.controller nothing makes a logical flow

Comment: This is fiddle [link] ( http://jsfiddle.net/soumyagangamwar/nr9gLuna/) Please check it

Answer (score 0):

Its normal to loose everythink when you refresh your page in angularJS (the major intrest of angularJs is that you have not to refresh your page !)

If you want to keep a value you need to store it in a database with an API or in a simpler way you can store it in the localstorage of the users browser.

```
localStorage.setItem('todos', JSON.stringify($scope.todos));
```

Exemple of a simple localstorage use in angular
[#Katie Harron](https://codepen.io/pibby/pen/DLtaK)

If that you call refresh is just state change you have to store your value in $rootScope